# How Retrieve a specific entity on mapping

Tags: mapping, struct

I'm trying to start a stacking smart contract. Each user can stake different ERC20 Token.

I'm using follwing struct :

```
   struct Token {
        address tokenAddress;
        uint256 stakedAmount;
        uint lastTransactionDate;
        bool isUsed;
    }
```

I define a relation User-Token with :

```
mapping(address => Token) stakingUserBalance;
```

On my stake function I need to store an ERC20 token for user :

```
function stakeToken(address tokenAddress, uint256 amount) public {
    require(amount > 0, "You cannot stake 0 token");

    //Transfer amount to smartcontract
    IERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);

    //Update user balance
    Token storage userToken = stakingUserBalance[msg.sender];
    userToken.lastTransactionDate = block.timestamp;
    userToken.stakedAmount += amount;
  

    //fire event
    emit TokenStaked(tokenAddress, amount);
}
```

So my question is : how get a specific token address in `stakingUserBalance` to update the value of `stakedAmount` for right token ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your use case each user (represented by an `address`) can stake a token (represented by an `address`) for which you store the information (represented by the `Token` struct) I would recommend to adjust your mapping structure to:

```js
// user address -> token address -> information
mapping(address => mapping(address => Token)) stakingUserBalance;
```

This allows you to access the information by using the following:

```js
Token storage userToken = stakingUserBalance[msg.sender][tokenAddress];
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you've defined the `Token` and `stakingUserBalance`, a user can only stake once type of token. User address is used as the only unique key. You'd have to restructure the data structure to use address-token as a unique combination.

One way would be to use a mapping of mapping.

`mapping (address => mapping(address => Token)) public stakedTokens;`

This would let create a mapping of `tokenAddress => Token` for each user address. This way, you can support multiple tokens for each user.

To access a token balance, you can use the following method.

`stakedTokens[userAddress][tokenAddress].stakedAmount;`

Hope this clarifies your questions.